# Django forms SMS confirmation with twilio

Tags: django, twilio

For about 2 years I'm practising Django web development, and now came that moment when I have to confirm form submitting with SMS verification code.

As I learned on some forums, peoples using twilio, but I could not solve have to bind it's all together to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ilyas, it would be helpful in the future to see an example of what you have tried. But we do have tutorials that should help you to get started quickly. The SMS 2FA Authentication tutorial (while written for Flask) should be a good model for your Django app as well.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/sms-two-factor-authentication/python/flask

First we validate the user with an email and password.

Second, we validate using a mobile device, by sending them a one-time verification code.

To send the verification code, we rely on the basics of [sending SMS in Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages):

```
def send_sms(to_number, body):
    account_sid = app.config['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
    auth_token = app.config['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    twilio_number = app.config['TWILIO_NUMBER']
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    client.messages.create(to=to_number,
                           from_=twilio_number,
                           body=body)
```

And we handle user registration via a form like so:

```
@app.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    form = SignUpForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.save_from_dict(form.as_dict)
        session['user_email'] = user.email
        send_confirmation_code(user.international_phone_number)
        return redirect(url_for('confirmation'))
    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

I hope this example will help you in tackling your Django project.